# can gravity be faster than light in some specific cases?

Tags: gravity, light

This is a follow up question from 
[If an event occurs at a point in space time what will an observer experience first, it's gravity or the light from it?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34479/if-an-event-occurs-at-a-point-in-space-time-what-will-an-observer-experience-fir)

This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive article on Wikipedia about Alcubierre drive says that faster than light travel is possible by manipulating space, though physically not possible, but if we transport a massive object using this drive, will the disappearance of the object's gravitational field be observed first or the disappearance of the object (EM Radiation) observed first? In simple words can gravity be faster than light in some cases?

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=Alcubierre

Comment: "Wikipedia about Alcubierre drive says that faster than light travel is possible by manipulating space, though physically not possible..." hmm, is possible though physically not possible? If you'd like to premise a question on a statement in Wikipedia, quote the exact statement, sentence or paragraph. Use the `>` symbol to display as a block quote. I was going to show an example but I found that the word manipulate or manipulating do not even appear in that article. *Don't paraphrase, quote exactly!*

Comment: @uhoh possible Mathematically impossible in reality. Is the only way it can have sense. Like a square root  of me^2 can be me or my negative :))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the influence of gravity instantaneous?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/5869/is-the-influence-of-gravity-instantaneous)

Comment: @try-catch-finally thanks, this helped.